# The addition formula of a kind of nonstandard elliptic integral

Tags: elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I'm looking for an algebraic addition formula for a class of nonstandard elliptic integrals.

\begin{align*}
r&=\frac{\sqrt{\left(1+pu\right)\left(1+u\right)\left(1-v\right)\left(1-qv\right)\,\,}+\sqrt{\left(1+pv\right)\left(1+v\right)\left(1-u\right)\left(1-qu\right)\,\,}}{2+p+q+\left(p-q\right)\left(u+v\right)-\left(p+q+2pq\right)uv}\\
s&=\frac{\sqrt{\left(1-\left(p+1\right)\left(q+1\right)r^{2}\right)\left(1-2\left(p+q\right)r^{2}\right)}-\left(1-p\right)r}{1-\left(p+q\right)\left(p+1\right)r^{2}}\\
w&=\frac{1-s^{2}}{ps^{2}-1}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{w}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+pt\right)\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t\right)\left(1-qt\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\\
&\qquad=\int_{0}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+pt\right)\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t\right)\left(1-qt\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad+\int_{0}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+pt\right)\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t\right)\left(1-qt\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align*}

> My question is whether I can find a more concise form of $w$

@Paramanand Singh

We can find the degenerate case, namely, $p=q=k$

\begin{align*}
w=\dfrac{u\sqrt{(1-v^2)(1-k^2v^2)\,}+v\sqrt{(1-u^2)(1-k^2u^2)\,}}{1-k^2u^2v^2}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\int_{0}^{w}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+kt\right)\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t\right)\left(1-kt\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\\
&\qquad=\int_{0}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+kt\right)\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t\right)\left(1-kt\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\\
&\qquad\qquad\quad+\int_{0}^{v}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+kt\right)\left(1+t\right)\left(1-t\right)\left(1-kt\right)}}\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align*}

Comment: I checked this post as I do visit elliptic-integrals tag frequently. You can not notify any user via '@' in a post. This is available only when you reply to a comment by that user. Apart from that I don't see any simpler formula right now. +1 for the effort of obtaining this and typing here as well.